# How to wait for response in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, http

What I am doing is putting the **filter on table** (contains records). When I type into search box (used http get method), table data get updated as per search box. But when I type very fast, then I see in console 500 Internal Server error.

The main problem is before comming previous response I am firing the next request.
There is no problem in result. Just *console shows every http request*. And in case of fast typing in search box it gets **red**.

**What is the solution for it?**

Comment: you can keep a scope variable which will set to true when get call is in process and after running then method that variable will again become false i.e we can again make a call.

Comment: You can use something called as chained promise using $q

Comment: not sure if that's gonna work but when you apply angular filter you can use `debounce` option like that: `<input type="text" ng-model="searchStr" ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}">` which will only filter after 1000ms after you stopped typing

Comment: set boolean loading=true before searching, if boolean if true, do not search again. on getting results back set false...

Answer (score 2):

you could trottle your search input :

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('TableController', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
        $http.get('yourTableData.json').then(function(result){
            $scope.rows = result.data;
        });

        $scope.filterText = '';

        var temp = '',
            filterTextTimeout;
        $scope.$watch('searchText', function (val) {
            if (filterTextTimeout){
               $timeout.cancel(filterTextTimeout);
            }    
            temp = val;
            filterTextTimeout = $timeout(function() {
                $scope.filterText = temp;
            $http.get($scope.filterText).then(function(result){ 
            $scope.rows = result;
            }
            }, 250);
        })
    });

    <input id="searchInput" type="search" placeholder="search field" ng-model="searchText" />
    <div class="record" ng-repeat="row in rows | filter:filterText">
        <span>{{row.content}}</span>
    </div>
```